# why the launcher show app icos is larger then the native launcher( build on android 4.2.2 source)

Tags: android, launcher

I compiled and build the launcher on the android 4.2.2 source code.

and I installed it on my Nexus 4,I found there's some differences between them.

I saw the code of *Launcher* and find it override *onCreateOptionsMenu()* ,but the native launcher dont have the menu in launcher.

I add a shortcut on the launcher I build .the ico is larger then native.

and the native app is mucher more efficient than I build.

so I Have some question .

- Is the open source code the same as the native app build source code ?
- Why the shortcut ico in "my launcher" is larger?
- The native launcher is more efficient,Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

To your manifest file. It is missing by default and causes the launcher to run in some sort of compatibility mode, which makes the icons enlarged.

Comment: I have watched your CircularSeekBar repo in github .haha~